# Get only visible text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Lets say I have some html like this:

```
<div id="content">Foo<span style='display:none'>hidden</span>Bar</div>
```

In reality this is more complicated and generated by angular using `ng-hide` and similar. I have a need to get all of the text from the `content` div that is visible to the user. In this case I would like to get `FooBar`.

`$('#content').text()` is the closest thing I have found, but that gives me `FoohiddenBar` in this case. Is there a good way to get just the visible contents of a div? I really need a `text()` function that skips hidden elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a clone, add it to the DOM (as pointed out by slindberg), remove all hidden elements, and then get the text :

```
var clone = $('#content').clone();

clone.appendTo('body').find(':hidden').remove();

var text = clone.text();

clone.remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lrqh/2/)

Comment: This works in the example, but in my actual app, the entire output div is made up of complicated angular tags. Almost everything gets removed with `clone.find(':hidden').remove();`, even the visible items. Very interesting.

Comment: If it's not valid markup, but for some reason contains angular tags and it can't be parsed with regular DOM traversal methods, you have a problem.

Comment: For some reason `clone.find(':hidden')` returns a much larger set than `$('#content').find(':hidden')` It is all valid markup. Perhaps it is because angular has not fully compiled the cloned elements?

Comment: Could be, I'm really not that familiar with angular !

Comment: I made it work by applying `show` or `hide` classes via angular in addition to just using `ng-hide`. `find('.hide')` seems to be more reliable in my case.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately @adeneo's answer won't work in most cases, since cloning creates a document fragment whose children are by definition not visible (they are not attached to the document) and are therefore all removed before `.text()` is called. This means that text of the element's children won't be included in the result.

The only way I've found to do this is to actually traverse all nodes top-down, omitting visually hidden nodes. Fortunately this can be expressed in a fairly concise plugin:

```js
jQuery.fn.visibleText = function() {
  return $.map(this.contents(), function(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
      return $(el).text();
    }
    if ($(el).is(':visible')) {
      return $(el).visibleText();
    }
  }).join('');
};
```

Note that this plugin assumes the selector's root element is not a text node (which is almost never the case). Also note that `$(el).text()` can be replaced with `el.textContent` if you don't have to support IE8.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YuJW/1/)

Comment: What do you mean it won't work? Did you try the Fiddle in my answer, it seems to work perfectly fine, and that's because jQuery's `:visible` pseudo selector doesn't care if the element is in the DOM or not.

Comment: The problem is that removing `:hidden` elements from the clone ends up removing all children because they are all considered hidden when detached from the document root. I've created [a fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lrqh/) that demonstrates the issue. I've updated my answer to be more clear about the problem.

Comment: I see what you mean, in this case it wouldn't matter, but it could matter if someone had other elements etc. I actually did find it in the documentation as well, *"Elements that are not in a document are not considered to be visible"*, so good point. I changed the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to modify the DOM in place to get the text, and then revert it back to the original when we're done with it.  The following does the trick:

```
function get_visible_text(content) {
    // Not so easy to get the visible text
    var saved = $(content).clone();
    // Remove the hidden parts
    $(content).find(':hidden').remove();
    // Get the remaining text
    var visible_text = $(content).text();
    // Now revert back to our saved version
    $(content).replaceWith(saved);
    return visible_text;
}
```

Note that @slindberg is correct, @adeneo's answer will not work because cloned objects are invisible until they are inserted into the DOM. By modifying the DOM in place, we avoid that problem.