# How to get content of element the same when it shown on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get content inside element and i want that is the same when it shown on browser

Example

```
<pre class="yyy">Hello this is <span style="display: none;"> test </span> text </pre>
```

and

```
// how to alert (get) content like when it shown on browser: Hello this is  text
alert($(".yyy").html());
```

I want alert result is: `Hello this is  text` the same when it shown on browser. Is that possible? how to do that thank.

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/4aLJ6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22518704/845680) is what you are looking for.

```
jQuery.fn.visibleText = function() {
  return $.map(this.contents(), function(el) {
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
      return $(el).text();
    }
    if ($(el).is(':visible')) {
      return $(el).visibleText();
    }
  }).join('');
};

alert($(".yyy").visibleText());
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4aLJ6/1/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this :

```
alert($(".yyy").clone().find(':not(:visible)').remove().end().text());
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/wokawo/1/edit)

Comment: This works in the example, but in my actual app it not working well.